# Loopback Filter Based On Related Model Properties

Tags: loopbackjs

I want to be able to filter based on the properties of related models. For example, I have a Class object with a Building object. I want to get a list of classes that take place in a certain building.

This filter

```
{  
   "include":"building",
   "scope":{  
      "where":{  
         "name":"warehouse"
      }
   }
}
```

returns **all** classes, but only includes building if its name is "warehouse". What I want is for the where clause on building name to apply to the whole filter so that I only get the class if it's building has that name.

Is there any way to do what I want?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in code, see [include with filters](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Include+filter#Includefilter-Includewithfilters) in the docs.

I'm not sure about the JSON but I think it should look more like this:

```
  "include": {
    "relation": "building",
    "scope": {
      "where": {"name": "warehouse"}
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

At the moment this is not possible. The issue has been described in this topic; https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/517

It looks like Strongloop is not going to implement this feature in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to use it on API CALL , you can follow a model like this one
and adapt it to your context.

//Here (as filter) , we get just the most recent message of a chat

```
{
 "include" : {
   "relation" :  "messages"  , 
   "scope" : 
     { 
       "order" : "createdAt DESC" , 
       "limit":1, 
       "skip":0
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment this is not possible in loopback, but you can use this component for resolve this ploblem. It is an easy to use and works perfectly.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/loopback-component-relation-filter

after you configure the component in the component-config.json file as the component documentation says. You can resolve your problem with.

assuming that the main model is called classes and that it has the relationship called building.

```
var filter = {  
   where: {
      building:{ name:"warehouse" }
   }
}

app.models.classes.find(filter, console.log);
```

That code only returns the classes when building name is warehouse.

Comment: You should reference that you are the maintainer of that package in your answer and provide some context on it

Comment: Please show an example of how you'd use that component to solve the problem.

Comment: Ready, I changed my answer and gave an example

Answer (score 0):

{
"error": {
"statusCode": 500,
"name": "MongoError",
"message": "unknown operator: $repetition",
"ok": 0,
"code": 2,
"codeName": "BadValue",
"stack": "MongoError: unknown operator: $repetition\n    at Connection.
}
}

I am getting this error when I try to filter with a relation property. I am using this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/loopback-component-relation-filter, but its not making a difference

Comment: I added this as an answer because I don't have enough reputation to comment.